# Java SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, mysql, jtable, simpledateformat

I have two 2 JTables.

Table_1 contains dates that are formatted to (`EE - MMMMM dd, yyyy`)

Table_2's values depends on what the user clicked on Table_1. Normally, the date format comming from the database is (`yyyy-dd-MM`) I formatted it to (`EE - MMMMM dd, yyyy`) to look a little bit good.

My problem is that, I want to format it back to (`yyyy-dd-MM`) for the query to work.

I want this:

```
Table_1.getValueAt(Table_1.getSelectedRow(),0) - > Thu - Feb 5, 2015
```

Back to this:

```
2015-5-2
```

And then query it to the database to bring results.

Comment: why don't you use the `SimpleDateFormat` again to get the correct output?

Comment: I've tried different ways and got lots of erros. Object cant be converted to Date, java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date Etc. etc.

Comment: Why you store the date as `char` not as `date`

Comment: If you want to compare date/time values, keep them as `Date` or whatever it is - don't try to compare string representations, basically.

Comment: You formated your `date` to store in db as char. That is not a good idea. Thats is what i mean.

Comment: As character? No i didnt..

Comment: I suggest, the table returns a `String`, and of course you're not able to directly cast a `String` to `Date`. But you can use the `SDF` to do this task for you.

Answer (score 1):

using `SimpleDateFormatter` and `Calendar`,

```
String date = "Thu-Feb 5, 2015";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE-MMM d, yyyy");

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(sdf.parse(date));

String newDate = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(newDate);
```

**output**,

```
Thu-Feb 5, 2015
2015-5-1
```

observe that `February` equals to `1` in above output, this is because a month starts from `0`.

Comment: And that 'newDate' that is a java.util.Date. I need to convert it to java.sql.Date because i will be using it in a query.

Comment: @meatno, `newDate` is of type `String`, not `Date`. You can convert this `String` to whatever type you want.